# errors while doing telnet on python 3 to CISCO router

Tags: python, networking, network-programming

Recently i have started learning python, and currently working on a small script to remote telnet from physical laptop to a router in GNS. Every connectivity is fine and i am able to telnet to the router via CMD using `telnet` command.

But when i am running my script instead of direct telnet command that where i am facing issue. Program runs fine without any issue, but telnet does not work.

I tried running debug as well on router can someone please check the script code and output from the debug command and advise what could be possible wrong.

**SCRIPT CODE:**

---

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib
HOST = "192.168.1.7"

tn =telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.1.7", "23")
user = input("Enter your username: ")
password = getpass.getpass()
tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
tn.write(user.encode("ASCII") + b"\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
    tn.write (password.encode("ASCII") + b"\n")
```

**OUTPUT OF DEBUG TELNET COMMAND ON CISCO:**

---

```
R2#
*Aug  6 16:50:15.095: Telnet2: 1 1 251 1
*Aug  6 16:50:15.095: TCP2: Telnet sent WILL ECHO (1)
*Aug  6 16:50:15.095: Telnet2: 2 2 251 3
*Aug  6 16:50:15.095: TCP2: Telnet sent WILL SUPPRESS-GA (3)
*Aug  6 16:50:15.095: Telnet2: 80000 80000 253 24
*Aug  6 16:50:15.099: TCP2: Telnet sent DO TTY-TYPE (24)
*Aug  6 16:50:15.099: Telnet2: 10000000 10000000 253 31
*Aug  6 16:50:15.099: TCP2: Telnet sent DO WINDOW-SIZE (31)
R2#
*Aug  6 16:50:23.451: TCP2: Telnet received DONT ECHO (1)
*Aug  6 16:50:23.451: TCP2: Telnet sent WONT ECHO (1)
*Aug  6 16:50:23.539: TCP2: Telnet received DONT SUPPRESS-GA (3)
*Aug  6 16:50:23.539: TCP2: Telnet sent WONT SUPPRESS-GA (3)
*Aug  6 16:50:23.543: TCP2: Telnet received WONT TTY-TYPE (24)
*Aug  6 16:50:23.543: TCP2: Telnet sent DONT TTY-TYPE (24)
*Aug  6 16:50:23.543: TCP2: Telnet received WONT WINDOW-SIZE (31)
*Aug  6 16:50:23.547: TCP2: Telnet sent DONT WINDOW-SIZE (31)
*Aug  6 16:50:23.567: TCP2: Telnet received DONT ECHO (1)
*Aug  6 16:50:23.571: TCP2: Telnet received DONT SUPPRESS-GA (3)
*Aug  6 16:50:23.571: TCP2: Telnet received WONT TTY-TYPE (24)
R2#
*Aug  6 16:50:23.571: TCP2: Telnet received WONT WINDOW-SIZE (31)
R2#
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or the program halts somewhere?

Comment: no the programs doesnot halt, i am also not getting any error.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Could you please write: 1. what did you expect; 2. what is happening instead

Comment: ok what i want is to telnet to the router using this script and run some commands, but when in am giving command inputs using 
tn.write(b"enable\n")
    tn.write(b"cisco\n")
    tn.write(b"conf t\n")
nothing happens. So i am suspecting my telnet is not working on first place and the above three line commands should not have any errors.

Comment: In addition to @holdenweb 's suggestions try adding `tn.set_debuglevel(lvl)` to gather more information. Further, if you are root on a Linux system, you could debug the telnet session with `tcpdump` or `wireshark` (or some Windows equivalent if you run Windows).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the rest of your Python script. But if you used `.read_all()` and you have no further commands to issue, you have to send `exit` command to the router
as `.read_all()` "reads all data until EOF as bytes; block until connection closed." (https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/telnetlib.html).

```
import getpass
import telnetlib
HOST = "192.168.1.7"

tn =telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.1.7", "23")
user = input("Enter your username: ")
password = getpass.getpass()
tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
tn.write(user.encode("ASCII") + b"\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
    tn.write (password.encode("ASCII") + b"\n")

.
.
.
tn.write(b"exit\n") # This line added if you don't have in your script

print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))
```

If you have further commands based on the output you receive, you may use: `read_until(expected, timeout=1)`
Read until a given byte string, expected, is encountered or until timeout seconds have passed.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know where your program is stopping - otherwise how can you know which statements are succeeding and which are failing?

For debugging purposes, insert a `print` call (or statement, if Python 2) after each statement, like

```
tn =telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.1.7", "23")
user = input("Enter your username: ")
password = getpass.getpass()
print"About to call tn.read")
tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
print"About to write username")
tn.write(user.encode("ASCII") + b"\n")
if password:
    print"Looking for password prompt")
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
    print"About to write password")
    tn.write (password.encode("ASCII") + b"\n")
```

One final thought: on the Cisco routers I used many years ago, the username prompt wouldn't appear until you'd entered a newline - so you could try adding a `tn.write(b'\n')` before the first `tn.read_until` call.